# Adding a View in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, view

In Rails -

I'm trying to add a `view`, let's call it `view3`, but am told `there are no available routes`. I also tried `rake routes` and indeed my additional view wasn't added.

What I tried to do:
I added both an `.html.erb` view file, and in the controller under the class that has the current views I added:

```
def view3
end
```

What else should I be doing is there an additional step? What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please provide your controller name?

Comment: It easy to ad views mapping with rails controller because if you need any functionality kind of requirement in your view page you can directly call your action.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a route (mapping between a URL and a controller action) to the `config/routes.rb` file. This would look something like this (assuming `things` is a resource you are modeling):

```
match '/things' => 'things#view3', :via => :get
```

`rake routes` only lists the routes that already exist.

Read this guide for more details : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

In routes you can add:

```
resources :your_controller_name
```

It will add or your views from your controller

Or for more routing options, you can also refer to the following documentation:

[Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)